# How to pass current page record id to the Lightning controller from component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

JS:

```
    ({
   openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },

   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "Fasle"  
       component.set("v.isOpen", false);
       var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction"); 
       dismissActionPanel.fire(); 

   },

   likenClose: function(component, event, helper) {
       debugger;
       // Display alert message on the click on the "Like and Close" button from Model Footer 
      // and set set the "isOpen" attribute to "False for close the model Box.
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
        var action = component.get("c.testupdate");
        action.setParams({ OrderID : component.get("v.recordId") });

       action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Alert the user with the value returned 
                // from the server
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

                // You would typically fire a event here to trigger 
                // client-side notification that the server-side 
                // action is complete
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });


  alert('Status Successfully Updated');  
       //var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction"); 

      // dismissActionPanel.fire();
              //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); 

            $A.enqueueAction(action);


   },
})`
```

MARKUP:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" controller="Testmodalbox">
  <!--use boolean attribute for Store true/false value,
    make default to "false" so modal box are not display on the load of component. 
    --> 
  <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

     <aura:handler name="init"  value="{!this}" action="{!c.openModel}"/>

  <!--Use "slds-m-around- -xx-large" class to add standard Large padding to the component--> 
  <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">

  <!--Use aura:if tag to display Model Box, on the bese of conditions. [isOpen boolean attribute] -->   
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

   <!--###### MODAL BOX Start From Here ######--> 
      <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header99" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
          <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Part Start From Here ######-->
          <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModel}">
            X
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2 id="header99" class="slds-text-heading--medium">About Sfdcmonkey.com</h2>
          </div>
          <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start From Here ######-->
          <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <p>Are you sure you want to cancel this campaign?
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start From Here ######-->
          <div class="slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModel}" >No</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.likenClose}">Yes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
      <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

 </aura:if>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

APEX:

```
public class Testmodalbox {
    @AuraEnabled
    Public  static void testupdate ( id OrderId){
        Order__c Order = [Select Status__c from Order__c where id =: OrderID];
        if (Order.Status__c == 'Pending For Cancel' || Order.Status__c == 'Cancelled') {
        }    else {
            Order.Status__c = 'Pending For Cancel';
            update Order;
        }       
}
}
```

Comment: Wht issue you are facing? You have implemented proper interface for getting recordID in component and you are passing same to apx?

Comment: Record is not updating,

Comment: You didnt mention that. Update your question with this accordingly.

Comment: can u update it for me, i don't know how to update

Comment: @Anuradha You can **[edit]** your own post to make any changes you need.

Comment: You should add some debug logs to your code to help you figure out what not be working and where, once you update your question, it will be better received. In the meantime, review [ask]